# Prove that $S$ is colorable if and only if it is orientable

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, orientation

I am taking a course on algebraic topology and I am trying to prove the following exercise:

> Let $S$ be a differentiable surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Prove that $S$ is colorable (you can paint one side blue and the other one red) if and only if it is orientable.

My first thought was using the compact surfaces classification, but $S$ is not required to be compact, so I do not know how to proceed. Also I don't know how to use the differentiability hypothesis.

Nevertheless, the intuition behind this exercise seems pretty obvious to me. If we consider a Möbius strip, we can move along the surface coming back to the same point so it only has one side but if we consider a orientation it has changed along the way. This makes clear that there must exist a connection between the two concepts.

The point seems to be a subtlety about colorability being inherent to the embedding, which I cannot totally grasp.

Comment: What is your definition of orientation?

Comment: My definition is: given a triangulation of the surface $S$, it is orientable if you can give an orientation to all the triangles in such a way that all triangles that share an edge have a compatible orientation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose your surface is oriented. With your definition you can color both sides of each triangle. For example, the clockwise side you paint blue, and the anti-clockwise side red. This colors your surface. Similarly, if the surface is colored, you can orient it as well, by saying that the blue side is clockwise (for each triangle).

Comment: Thank you, I was on the wrong track. But there is one thing that is still not clear to me. The text I am following mention that while being orientable is an intrinsic property, being colorable is not, it depends on the embedding.

But I don't see why your answer can be generalised to a surface in $\mathbb{R}^n$. The triangles are always in $\mathbb{R}^2$ so I can consider them in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and assign them a color like you did and having the equivalence again, can't I?